# What is the prefix of an XML document which does not have a prefix defined?

Tags: xml, namespaces, msxml, serverxmlhttp

**Update**
Thanks to florent I now realize I used the wrong term in the question (originally: 'What is the namespace of an XML document which does not have a namespace defined?').
Also, I think now I am asking two questions:
1. can one assign a prefix to an XML document which does not have a prefix? (probably yes, but how does one do this with classic ASP?)
2. what is the XPath location path of a node in an XML document which does not have a prefix defined? If this is even possible.

I have classic ASP code which retrieves an XML document using the MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0 object, but the XML document does not have a prefix defined. I can't change the way the XML document is made.

This is how the XML looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<SearchResultsResponse xmlns="http://openapi.somesite.com/openapi-3.0.0">
[...]
</SearchResultsResponse>
```

The document is automatically parsed and accessable trough the .responseXML property. But looking up nodes with:

```
Set objData = obj_http.responseXML.selectSingleNode("//someNodeName")
Response.Write "Data: " & objData.Text
```

doesn't work. (I get a 'Object Required' error message, meaning no node was found.) And

```
Response.Write obj_http.responseXML.documentElement.prefix
```

gives me an empty string.

One way to make this work is to use `.selectSingleNode("//*[local-name() = 'someNodeName']")`, but I guess this is not very efficient in larger XML documents. (Or am I wrong there?)

I have read that something like: `.selectSingleNode("//ns:rootNodeName/ns:childNodeName")`, where 'ns' is the prefix defined, should be the way to go, but then what should I use for the prefix if none is defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out:

```
Dim obj_XML
Set obj_XML = obj_http.responseXML

' this is where the magic happens, 'ns' is defined as the prefix:
obj_XML.setProperty _
    "SelectionNamespaces", _
    "xmlns:ns='http://openapi.somesite.com/openapi-3.0.0' " &_
    "xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'"

Dim obj_node
' now we can get the node with an XPath location path with the 'ns' prefix:
Set obj_node = obj_XML.selectSingleNode("//ns:SearchResultsResponse/ns:SessionId")

If obj_node Is Nothing Then
    Response.Write "# No node found #<br />"
Else
    Response.Write "Node text: " & obj_node.Text & "<br />"
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand "http://openapi.somesite.com/openapi-3.0.0" is the namespace of the document. It just doesn't have a prefix defined so this is the default namespace.

> I have read that something like:
>   .selectSingleNode("//ns:rootNodeName/ns:childNodeName"), where 'ns' is
>   the namespace defined, should be the way to go, but then what should I
>   use for the namespace if none is defined?

"ns" here is not the namespace but the namespace prefix. I'm not an ASP person so I cannot help much with the code but you should still be able to define a namespace for your node lookup. You should even be able to redefine it with a prefix if you don't want to use the default namespace.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Being new to XML I used the wrong term. I will update my question.

Comment: I'm not familliar with msxml so I cannot say much about the special case. But you can always redefine the prefix, also in your parser (in xslt for example) and then use this prefix in your xpath.

Comment: look here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/xmlandnetfx/thread/5ae834d2-59ed-44d6-b6da-0a7bf5795caa

you should be able to redefine the namespace with a property:

objResponse.responseXML.setProperty("SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:myns='http://openapi.somesite.com/openapi-3.0.0'")
objResponse.responseXML.selectSingleNode("//someNodeName")